Can html-midi-player visualizers be made to wrap around?
I am making a web app for mobile devices that can display MIDI files as a music staff. I am currently using html-midi-player to do so. However, I need the staff to be able to wrap around and display more lines. This way people don't need to constantly scroll. I tried looking at the docs for both html-midi-player and magenta/music, the library html-midi-player uses, but couldn't find any answers.
Here's my current code:
<div class="container-fluid vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-center">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-center text-start">
        <midi-visualizer
            type="staff"
            id="myVisualizer"
            src="/test.mid">
        </midi-visualizer>
        <midi-player
            src="/test.mid"
            sound-font visualizer="#myVisualizer">
        </midi-player>
    </div>
</div>

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
